# How to get ids from divs that were dragged into a drop zone on button click javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find a way to get the ids from dragged divs after they are in the drop zone.

All the drag components have an id from drag1 - drag8 and the drop zone is div drop zone. Because there are no divs in the drop zone when the page loads I want to gather the ids on a save button for now with a text box entry and drop down menu select.

I have tried the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropzone div").click(function() {
        var index = $("#dropzone div").index(this);
        $("#dropzone_drag").html("Index " + drag + " was clicked");
    });
});
```

And I use jQuery for the text box, which works nicely:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#save').click(function() {
        alert($('#name').val());
    });
});
```

How do I find the ids from dragged divs after they are in the drop zone?

Comment: It was only an idea for the code above is a rough test and any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
  <script>
  var div = document.getElementById('dropzone')
  </script>
```

and on the button i added:

```
alert( div.innerHTML )
```

The result gave me all of the div information from it's html page so i could select the information i wanted to push to the database.

Thank you all for you input and advice.

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

In my comprehension .index(this) returns the index of the element relative to the list "#dropzone div"., which may or may not contain the elements in the order you want. But if all your elements have a common class, say ".foo_bar" it probably would be easier to know the id given an clicked element.

Otherwise, as you're using this on the function, if this is one of your "drags" it is probably easier to pick the id from this than to try the indexes.

Try doing it like that and maybe it'll word better.

```
ids = {};
$("#dropzone>div").each(function(){
    ids[$(this).prop('id')] = $(this).prop('id').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

the code .replace() means that we are removing characters (in this case anything that isn't a number) from the string so we end up with it's true number. Instead of it's place in the DOM.

If i didn't comprehend well your problem, correct my comprehension errors and i will edit the answer. And an html of the zones would be nice ;)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using html drag and drop, that lets you drop any of the 8 components (and multiples of) to make up an email. After dropping is complete I need to click on a save button which will keep a record of the components used that were dropped in order to be sent to a database. Id is enough as the components are different from each other. I currently have a text box which the save button gets it's value and i need to add the components to this list.

Comment: Matthew, i can't comment in your post or answer so i will comment here:
try console.log(ids) and console.log(this) inside your .each so you will know what is "it" and how youre populating the object. (wouldn't it be better to use a list? a list is: var a = [])

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thank you for your response, yes it is better to do a list. I will give your suggestions a try and let you know.

Comment: After trying the code i get a result of undefined or it crashes.

Comment: Crash shouldn't happen... The code shouldn't crash, but undefined could mean "this" has no .prop(id), although i think no prop(id) should return "", or that you're accessing an index higher than the last element ( remember the count starts at 0 not at 1 so it ends at n-1 ).
Something you should think about is: the order of the elements in the DOM matter, so let's say the first element is ID=8, it'll be the first element on your list ( element 0 ), so if the others are in order the list would be: [8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].
My sugestion, try an object as the one i will add to my answer soon.

Comment: It more freezes than crashes                                                                                     I am upto this:       <script>
      var div = document.getElementById('dropzone')
      </script> and i have this alert on the save button:   alert( div.innerHTML ) which gives a result of everything, all of the div code is there

Comment: It must always start with the first component as it's the header, and end in part 8 which is the footer. generally the email will only be made of 3-4 components

Answer (score 0):

After playing around i came up with the following:

```
var ids = {};
$("#dropzone>div").each(function(i){
    ids[i] = $(this).prop('id');
});
```

which at the moment says undefined, but i did manage to put it on the save button so it no longer pops up when i open the page.

Any suggests please?

Comment: <script>
var ids = {};
$("div[id^='drag']").each(function(i){
    ids[i] = $(this).prop('id');
});
</script>

Comment: Which returns only 1 value and sadly it's the wrong value